# Restricting output of hoogle on ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have hoogle installed on my box and I can use hoogle from within ghci. Is there a way to ask hoogle to search only within certain modules and packages?

I tried

```
:hoogle +System.Directory directory
```

but I get a lot of results that are not found in the System.Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your `:hoogle` command is defined in your `.ghci` file?

I have:

```
:def hoogle \x -> return $ ":!hoogle \"" ++ x ++ "\""
```

and your example works for me.

To debug the problem further, try (note the `!`):

```
:!hoogle +System.Directory directory
```

This directly executes the `hoogle` function on your system - so if that doesn't work it's a problem with your `hoogle` executable.

Comment: What I meant was that it gave a list of package names that have the word 'directory' in their names when in fact, I'm looking only for functions within System.Directory module that have the word 'directory' somewhere in their name

Comment: That is the standard behavior of `hoogle`. You can always write your own wrapper to remove the entries you don't want.